# How to get Related Keywords from a Keyword in the Order they are attached?

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.5, keyword

Scenario:

Category : `CatA`
Keyword  : `KeywordA`

Related Keywords in KeywordA(In The Order They are linked): `KeywordB, KeywordC, KeywordF, KeywordE, KeywordD`

Sample TCM IDs(Order of Creation):

```
KeywordB: tcm:1-1-1024
KeywordC: tcm:1-2-1024
KeywordD: tcm:1-3-1024
KeywordE: tcm:1-4-1024
KeywordF: tcm:1-5-1024
```

Now, when I try to fetch the Related Keywords for KeywordA from the DXA Application using `GetRelatedKeywordUris()` method, I get the related keywords in the order they are created, not in the order they are linked in the Related Keywords of KeywordA.

Means, the result which I get is `KeywordB, KeywordC, KeywordD, KeywordE, KeywordF`

Result Expected is : `KeywordB, KeywordC, KeywordF, KeywordE, KeywordD`

Can anyone help, how I can get the result in order they are linked in Related Keywords?

[image]

Thanks,
Sharad Kumar Sangal

Answer (score 1):

This scenario you are referring, already asked in Trex you can refer the below link

[Tridion related keyword ordering is not maintained correctly](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/tridion-related-keyword-ordering-is-not-maintained-correctly)

Comment: Hi Priyank, I went through that, but what to put in custom compareTo method, as we are not sorting by Key or Name.

Comment: This may be a (old) Known Issue, but if the CME allows you to order the related Keywords, it is a reasonable expectation that you can retrieve them in that order. I would report this with SDL Customer Support.